# Sharepoint 2007 C# add multichoice field as checkboxes

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss

I'm developing a Sharepoint 2007 application with Visual Studio 2008 / C#.

I have a  FeatureReceiver to build lists programatically on feature activation. That all works fine.

Normal Mutichoice field can be added this way:

```
myList.Fields.Add(title, type, required, false, choices);
```

My question is: How can I add a Multichoice field as checkboxes to my list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SPFieldType.MultiChoice for 2nd parameter...

Comment: Will it automatically set to checkboxes? Because in the UI you can chose between checkboxes and radiobuttons.

Comment: @PatrickP It does, radio buttons is not multichoice type since you can only select one value...

Answer (score 1):

Using `SPFieldType.MultiChoice` field type gives you check boxes in the UI.

However, if you ever need a choice field with radio buttons, the [choice field class `SPFieldChoice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx) has a [property `EditFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.editformat.aspx) that allows to specify one of the two options for how to display selections:

- `SPChoiceFormatType.Dropdown` - drop-down list box
- `SPChoiceFormatType.RadioButtons` - option buttons

Comment: @Marek - It is not so difficult to programatically create a choice filed with radio buttons... it is very simple, you can use 'SPFieldChoice.EditFormat = SPChoiceFormatType.RadioButtons;' and call Update method... so simple right? :)